# Hadoop Job reading from local or writing to blob

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have a problem with getting my mapreduce Job running. The problem I think is the configuration.

My Job has two parameters: *input* and *output* directory. The problem is, the Job has internal code to prepare data for itself, to be precise: 
It checkout repositories form github to *input* location given as parameter, and then saves the output in *output* directory. So when i run my Job locally `hadoop jar myjar.jar input output` the Job checkout the source files to *input* directory and read form there as well.

But that is not the case when it comes to run it in HDInsight. I've uploaded via scp the jar file and fired it up by `yarn jar hadoop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar input output`. As supposed the Job was reading form the blob storage instead form jar location, but the internal code was writing to local filesystem so my job haven't seen input files.

I see two options here. First, preferred one, is to configure hadoop to read form local filesystem, so the Job will see the check-outed files. Second one is to somehow checkout the source code from github to blob *input* directory. I tried to run job passing as *input* directory an wsab (wasb://YOURDefaultContainer@YOURStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/SomeDirectory/ASubDirectory/) uri, but that didn't work either.

I am using jgit to checkout source files:

> File destination = new File(inputDir + "/" + project);
>   Git.cloneRepository().setURI(uri).setDirectory(destination).call();

Thank You for Your help.

Comment: <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>wasb://blob@cluster.blob.core.windows.net</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>

Comment: I'm playing with configuration and I'm not sure if I'm gonna change the _fs.default_ to _file:///_ instead _wasb_ if it gonna work on all my clusters nodes or only in local  mode?